# dateCreated, lastUpdated fields in Grails 2.0

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-2.0

I've got an application that was using Grails 1.3.7 which I've just migrated to Grails 2.0. The application makes use of the automatic `dateCreated` and `lastUpdated` fields to manage the timestamps associated with creation and modification of the objects. After upgrading, I get the following error:

```
| Running Grails application
| Error 2012-01-29 22:36:53,504 [Thread-8] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ERROR: null value in column "date_created" violates not-null constraint
| Error 2012-01-29 22:36:53,510 [Thread-8] ERROR events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session
```

Commenting out the above mentioned fields in my Domain Classes makes the problem go away.

Have the `dateCreated` and `lastUpdated` fields been deprecated in Grails 2.0? If so, does that mean that I have to write the code to handle this functionality manually or has the code been moved to a plugin of some sort, like the [audit-trail](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-trail) plugin?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, fixed it by manually setting the autoTimestamp variable to "true" in the domain class definitions:

```
static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp true
}
```

I would guess that this property is not set after migrating a project from Grails 1.3.7 to 2.0.0.

Comment: thank you so much! I ran into an issue because grails 2.2.0 was overriding the value I was setting in domain class. And more dangerous thing is the timeStamp added by Grails is system clock dependent.

Comment: I fixed the automatic overriding by setting the autoTimestamp property to `false`

Answer (score 6):

Grails 2.0 still supports the automatic timestamps.  [It's listed in the manual (scroll **up** a bit from this link)](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#ormdsl).

However, it specifically mentions:

> If you put `nullable: false` constraints on either `dateCreated` or `lastUpdated`, your domain instances will fail validation - probably not what you want. Leave constraints off these properties unless you have disabled automatic timestamping.

Comment: The link you posted goes to http://localhost/~phil/. Did you put the wrong link in?

Comment: Neither of the fields are mentioned at all in the constraints. Based on the quoted text I'm starting to think that I may have somehow disabled "automatic timestamping". Where did you get that text from?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was browsing my offline copy.  The link has been fixed.  The warning message is on the page I linked.  You have to scroll ***UP*** from the link, because I can't link directly.

Comment: Ok, fixed it by manually setting the autoTimestamp variable to "true" in the domain class definitions. I would guess that this property is not set after migrating a project from Grails 1.3.7 to 2.0.0.

Comment: I believe Grails 2.X still has autoTimestamp as a default behavior, as OverZealous stated, but I wonder if perhaps there are particular plugins that are overriding it. I have projects that work just fine with this, and yet I've just now seen on of our apps at work start exhibiting this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in Grails 2.0.3 that can cause this problem when using Postgres. See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8988. The issue says it will resolved when 2.0.4 is released.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate solution if you're working in Grails 4:

```
class ScheduledTaskServiceSpec extends Specification implements ServiceUnitTest<ScheduledTaskService>{

    @Shared @AutoCleanup HibernateDatastore hibernateDatastore
    @Shared AutoTimestampEventListener timestamper

    void setupSpec() {
        hibernateDatastore = new HibernateDatastore(RegistrationCode)
        timestamper = hibernateDatastore.getAutoTimestampEventListener()
    }

    @Transactional
    @Rollback        
    void 'some test method'() {
        when:
        timestamper.withoutDateCreated(MyDomainClass) {
            MyDomainClass mdc = new MyDomainClass(name:"foo")
            mdc.dateCreated = new Date() - 20
        }

        then:
        MyDomainClass.findByName("foo").dateCreated < new Date()
    }
}
```

### Reference

[AutoTimestampEventListener](https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/api/org/grails/datastore/gorm/events/AutoTimestampEventListener.html)